# Sql id and plan creation pattern

Tags: oracle, performance-tuning

Oracle database.
I've got this customer who is complaining about some ODI application taking longer than before (meh!).
Currently, it is not clear what the app does (I'm asking..) but he told me that they every time "drop, recreate and gather statistics" on tables.
My questions are:

- Isn't it useless to gather stats on a new table?
- If I launch a query on a table, a sql_id and a plan are generated. If I drop-recreate the same table will the same query have the same sql_id and plan hash value as before?
  I'm asking this because, I see that one of the queries which they're complaining about has only 39 executions and has a really high execution time:

```
MIN(SNAP_ID) MAX(SNAP_ID)        MAX        AVG SUM(EXECUTIONS_DELTA) PLAN_HASH_VALUE
------------ ------------ ---------- ---------- --------------------- ---------------
       27135        27311 744.824186 430.504395                    39       867694248
```

Comment: "*Isn't it useless to gather stats on a new table?*" - not if "recreate" includes populating the table with data.

Comment: If the new table name is the same and the query is the same the SQL_ID value will be the same. If the statistics are different or if bind variable values (if any) are different then the plan could change which would result in a different value for PLAN_HASH_VALUE. The statistics would be different if the data changes between times when the stats are gathered. You should gather statistics after dropping, recreating, and reloading a table because otherwise the database has to do dynamic sampling to get statistics and that may sample few rows and be inaccurate compared to a larger sample.

Comment: @BobbyDurrett Thank you.